# How creating XeLatex cweb document

Tags: xetex, cweb

Im using fedora. I have trouble with correct polish letter ąźżć etc.
How write example in cweb?
I prefer latex not plain tex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid there's not much people here using CWEB, so maybe a small example would be useful.

Comment: CWEB is built on Plain TeX. It loads its own macro package (cwebmac.tex) in addition. If you want Unicode support you could try compiling with xetex (not xelatex), but I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 2):

By trial and error, I came to this. This is complete working example using Latex and some plain TeX definition together. This example is not perfectly.

```
% -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
\documentclass[a4paper]{cweb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\begin{document}
@* Wstęp. To jest początek. A to kolejna linia zakończona znakiem |'\n'|. Znak {\tt końca linii} jest specyficzny dla każdego systemu.
@d MAX_1 50
@p
#include <stdio.h>
@#
int main(void)
{
@<Definicja tablicy@>@;
 printf(napis);return 0;}
@

@ @<Definicja tablicy@>=
char napis[]="Żółć"; /* typ znakowy */
@
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Niestety Żółć w programie została zamieniona na Zółć

Comment: That's the price to pay for not using Unicode fonts. Now, have you tried to tangle this code?

Comment: I dont know how change this code